# DNS and NTP not working after installing NetworkManger on Raspberry Pi

Tags: linux, raspbian-buster, dns, ntp, networkmanager

can anyone help me, this issue has been driving me mad for 4 months, I have very limited experience with any form or Linux and at a complete loss at to how to make it work.

I have a Raspberry Pi 4 1Gb running the Raspbian Buster with desktop and recommended software September 2019.

I have installed Samba for network file sharing, and NetworkManger to create a hotspot (NetworkManger is in default configurations). However once I have powered off the Raspberry Pi and then the power it back up at a later time, the system time is not synced/updated, any website visited in chromium return name not resolved issues I can’t access any online resources for things like updating or installing anything new. However, I can connect to Raspberry Pi from my desktop using WinSCP, PuTTY and access the network file sharing folders, I can Ping and traceroute IPs form the Raspberry Pi both Local and online addresses. But just cannot get DNS and NTP to work, if that is even the problem.

I have been searching for a solution whatever NetworkManger is braking for months, so many forums have posts that are 10+ years old and are completely useless as none of their suggestions matches anything available on the Raspberry Pi.

Any help anyone can give will be greatly appreciated as driving me mad for over 4 months leaving all my Raspberry Pi’s useless until I can find a solution, Thank You.

Following instructions from websites and YouTube videos and from the point of a fresh install on the SD card of as stated above Raspbian Buster with desktop and recommended software September 2019, here are all the commands in order that where ran:

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install samba samba-common-bin
cd /home/pi/Documents
sudo mkdir -m 1777 /home/pi/Documents/Accounting\ Solutions
sudo leafpad /etc/samba/smb.conf
```

[Accounting Solutions]
Comment = Accounting Solutions
Path = /home/pi/Documents/Accounting Solutions
Browseable = yes
Writeable = Yes
only guest = no
create mask = 0777
directory mask = 0777
Public = yes
Guest ok = yes

```
sudo cp /home/pi/Templates/smb.conf /etc/samba/smb.conf
sudo smbpasswd -a pi
sudo /etc/init.d/samba restart
sudo /etc/init.d/samba-ad-dc restart
sudo /etc/init.d/smbd restart
samba reboot'

sudo apt update
sudo apt install network-manager network-manager-gnome openvpn \openvpn-systemd-resolved network-manager-openvpn \network-manager-openvpn-gnome
sudo apt purge openresolv dhcpcd5
sudo ln -sf /lib/systemd/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf
sudo reboot
```

Comment: Raspbian **DOES NOT** use Network Manager - although you can install it (if you are a glutton for punishment). You are unlikely to get much help on this site.

Comment: If you want help you need to explain what you did. How did you install Network Manager? Did you disable `dhcpcd`? I am assuming you are using Raspbian-Buster, but you should explicitly state.

Comment: Following instructions from websites and YouTube videos and from the point of a fresh install on the SD card of as stated above Raspbian Buster with desktop and recommended software September 2019, I have edited the above to include all the commands in order that where ran from a fresh install.